# sorting UITableview rows in a UI Segmented Controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a Segmented controller to control how data is presented in my table view. One of the views should be chronologically which is easy because I use firebase so the query is effectively already chronological. However, I want to sort by highest rated which is a computed value (the "number of likes" is the count of a child which is an array of users who clicked "like". the table view controller instantiates an array:

```
    var media = [Media]()
```

and a function fetches the media and ends like this:

```
    let ref = DatabaseReference.media.reference()

            let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: (value))

            query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])

                if !self.media.contains(media) {
                    self.media.insert(media, at: 0)
```

I think I need to make 2 different arrays and use a switch statement on segmented controller before the last 2 lines to populate them, then use switch statements in my TableView Data Source to read the associated arrays. Is this the right idea? If so, how do I sort snapshots?

Comment: nope you don't need two arrays, you need to use higher order functions to sort your data

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean